# Eeeek! Where did the reputation graph go?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, reputation-graph

The reputation graph no longer shows up on my profile when I click on the reputation tab. Is it gone now (like the mail icon)? Or has it been moved somewhere else?

I do like the more detailed summary of reputation earned. Is it possible to still keep some form of graph for easy visualization of reputation over time?

[image: Eek]

Comment: If you are interested I wrote a little app a while back that will let you plot your reputation. http://code.google.com/p/se-reputation-compare/downloads/list

Comment: @Wikis Commit At Area 51, Let's find out ;)

Comment: No offense to Eek the Cat, but so far all this "Eeeek!" title has done is cause more duplicates to get asked! Look [at that Linked column](http://i.imgur.com/XX0an.png "Why aren't people even seeing the suggestions?") continue to grow!

Comment: The reputation graph is on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Hey Matt, now look at your chart. B/c of my upvote, you now got 1000!!!

Answer (score -11, accepted):

We decided to pull the graph, as it was not very useful, too complex, and increasingly out of date.

edit: the reformulated, more useful graph is here:

- user profile
- reputation tab
- graph subtab

[image]

Comment: Hi Jeff.  The new graph is very well done, and very professional -1 to +1, not that you were terribly concerned :)  I'm really not trying to cavil, but I, and a lot of other people would very much appreciate having a way to also load the old graph.  As a previous commenter noted, it was nice to see your "journey" through SO on it.  I know that might sound silly, but I think a lot of people share that opinion.  Food for thought.

Comment: @adam if you need that, see http://stackapps.com/questions/2202/reputation-graph

Comment: This graph is not **fun**.

Comment: @eonil it's even better than fun, it's actually useful!

Comment: @Jeff, you gave me Excel taking away WoW. Choosing one of this is hard problem. However I was far more loved WoW.

Comment: @Eonil - why should there be a choice?  I'm pretty sure you can install WoW and Excel side-by-side on the same computer, and use whichever you want to at any given time :)

Comment: @Adam, well... your word is right too. And I also love Mac than Linux. So it had became problem about choice. I'm just wishing Jeff doesn't take even *Badges* away from me :)

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: I find this bar chart useless to me since I don't have a lot of reputation traffic. Any chance for the old-school representation to make a reappearance as a second option? Graph posted by balpha on stackapps is (without meaning any disrespect to balpha)… uglier :)

Comment: @Adam: well, employers tend to take a dim view of it if you do that ...

Comment: @ivan that's available on your http://stackexchange.com profile

Comment: @Jeff: Thanks! That one looks awesome!

Answer (score 59):

There's a [user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2202/reputation-graph) which will create a graph - arguably nicer than the original

[image]

Comment: It's probably definitively nicer, since it probably won't fall for all of the horrendous errors that the original had with things like negative ratings.

Comment: +1, something like this should be included by default without having to use a UserScript.

Comment: @0xA3, give them time...

Comment: @Benjol: Sure, for me this is no essential feature, it's rather a nice-to-have one ;)

Comment: +1, At least we can have some sort of graph (and I like this one better).

Comment: Very nice, thanks. And agree, it's nicer than the original.

Answer (score 44):

I miss the old reputation graph ... but wait it's back!

Just go to your Stack Exchange account (I clicked on my programmers coffee cup icon on my combined flair image) and choose 'reputation' and you get a reputation graph across all your 200+ reputation accounts!

[image: My reputation graph]

Who says that SO is an unthinking machine.

Comment: It is awesome (though private), but it is not easy to find if coming from http://stackexchange.com/. Tip: click on "logged in" (upper middle, to the left of "log out"). If "log in" is displayed instead of "logged in" then log in first. And then click on "reputation" (below the profile text). If the mouse cursor is moved in the graph it displays the exact reputation points and exact date.

Comment: Why aren't these things better organized? Do we really have to click every link we can find on each Stack Exchange site before we get to stuff that's gone/been moved/just introduced?

Comment: @Alex, totally.  I struggle to see the utility in the SE people spending time and energy moving/eliminating things users seem to be pretty happy with.

Comment: @amelvin, any explination why Area51 isn't on this graph?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the [global reputation line graph](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82817/eeeek-where-did-the-reputation-graph-go/83879#83879) that you can get on your stackexchange.com profile, there is also a per-site graph accessible from your profile page.

Instead of being on the landing page, there is now a "graph" option. Selecting it will provide a bar graph readout, divided into the same pagination as your reputation page normally displays. You can hover over a bar to look at the exact reputation for that day, and clicking it will provide a readout for that individual day.

In the end, this provides a very different utility than the global reputation line graph, but that just means you have more tools to analyze your trends in reputation growth. ♪

Below is a sample, including the readout for clicking an individual day.

[image: Image of a reputation graph on the profile page]

Comment: There is a bug reported with this - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84373/reputation-graph-not-displaying-details-correctly

Comment: @ChrisF I'm not able to reproduce that. See my comment over there. Either it's already been resolved, or maybe there's something afoot that is causing it.

Comment: Thanks! It would be nice if the different forms of rep would be colored differently. Like all "hard" rep which is affected by the rep cap and then on top of it the other rep which isn't affected. This shows better when/whether the rep cap was hit.

Comment: @Martin On any time period when you have surpassed the reputation cap on at least one day, there is a grey line that indicates the reputation cap. This tells you, for example, that [Jon Skeet hasn't gone below 200 rep per day since June 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_graph "That's more imposing than his steep cliff of a line graph, in my opinion"). But seeing the breakout between votes and non-votes by color, that could be cool and show interesting statistics. I sincerely suggest making a feature-request for that.

Comment: I assume you mean the gray line at 200rep. I can't see any other gray line. That line isn't that meaningful, because you can go over 200rep without hitting the cap. I will open the feature-request.

Comment: I opened now the [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84438/156875) for this.

Answer (score 5):

- The graph was flawed.  Some were way off.
- It represented an actual view of reputation meaning some users graphs showed them a few hundred below zero.
- It wasn't much use as you couldn't tell small differences very easily.

I would not be surprised if it is gone for good.

Comment: Could someone explain 'actual' reputation? What's the alternative, virtual reputation??

Comment: I disagree that it wasn't much use -- I found it very useful for giving an overview across all the time you've been registered on a site. What the graph lacked was a facility to zoom in - e.g. to view only the most recent week, month, quarter or year and change the range of *both* axes appropriately.

Comment: @one: If you're downvoted when you have 1 rep, the number under your name does not go down.  The graph did.

Comment: @one: *"I disagree it wasn't much use"* Obviously it wasn't useful enough for all the people who complained that that was their only way to see rep changes.  *See: [Eeeek!  What happened to my envelope?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope)*

Comment: @John Thx for explaining 'actual rep'. I agree it shouldn't be the *only* way to see rep *changes*, but I'm saying i found it very useful as *a* way to present a longer-term perspective visually.

Comment: As I see it, the graph was never meant to be a precise representation of history. The graph is supposed to show a long-term overview. I just love StackOverflow for the plenty of statistics it provides, and the graph was my favorite page on the website. It was so fun to see the steep curves in the weeks when I contributed more!

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the missing envelope, the official answer is the most downvoted one in this thread:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope

Regarding the graph, see John's answer.

Comment: I'm aware of the Eeeek post. I was just using it as a comparison noting the recent changes. Thanks for the reminder though, in case I didn't see the post.

Comment: Eeek! Link broken! (as expected)

Comment: @belisarius: OMG! That's the most blatant form of censorship!!

Comment: Now, I am pretty sure that one never existed. And yet I've a deja-vu ...

Comment: @belisarius: It didn't exist? It was the 6th most rated question on MSO, and contained the most down-voted answer by Jeff Atwood to date. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76333/site-autonomy-and-governance-community-driven-democracy-or-benevolent-dictatorsh/83340#83340

Comment: @augustin I was joking. I was tempted to create sock puppets just to be able to upvote that one more than one time (and downvote the answer too)

Comment: @belisarius: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76333/site-autonomy-and-governance-community-driven-democracy-or-benevolent-dictatorsh/83340#83340

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: WTF is going on here? Why was that thread about the envelope deleted? Can't you accept criticism and community feedback? Obviously, you screwed up there, accept it! Deleting that thread just shows that your FAQ about "community driven" is plain BS! Besides, there were a lot of good ideas in it, some of which you already used...

Comment: @Daniel calm down. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83253/what-topics-can-be-discussed-here/83332#83332 Btw, Jeff won't get notified if you comment on a post he hasn't participated in.

Comment: @balpha: I completely agree with @sbi's POV on the answer you just linked to. Luckily stuff like that isn't happening on SO, I better stick to that site... The little I have seen happening on MSO so far makes me go wild

Comment: @sbi: That's just sad. And makes me go wild again ;-) See ya @SO :-)

Comment: @Wether Eeeek! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Now do a backup of everything you've just said before Jeff deletes it (by the way, Jeff's not very good with backups).

Comment: @alex I am unwrapping my new 2 petabytes home SAN

Comment: @Wether: Just now?! I've done that long ago.

Answer (score 2):

I like the new graph. But the key thing I find missing from the old one is a sense of trajectory. You can take a quick look at it and see the rate of my "growth" on a site. The new graph type is good for seeing periods of activity, but doesn't give that same *trend* sense.

The new private graph does a decent job for showing me my own reputation trends in this way, but it'd be nice to see it for other people too.