# What happened to the Reputation Chart/Graph?

Tags: support, reputation-graph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where did the reputation graph go?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82817/where-did-the-reputation-graph-go)

I looked at my reputation tab on my profile and now the graphical chart is missing. I would like that chart back because it gives a really nice overview.

Comment: By the way, I like the new list. The old list was not very good.

Comment: [(I already asked the question)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82863/what-happened-to-reputation-graph)..any way ..@Jeff Atwood: are there any plans for new Graph?

Answer (score 0):

We decided to pull the graph, as it was not very useful, too complex, and increasingly out of date.

Comment: Any plans for a new graph?