# Why is the search not showing recent matches by Title when I sort by newest?

Tags: support, search, meta

I just posted a question [What happened to the Reputation Chart/Graph?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82869/what-happened-to-the-reputation-chart-graph-closed) which turned out to be a duplicate.

Before I posted this duplicate, I did a search first for [Reputation Chart](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=Reputation%20Chart) and [Reputation Graph](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=Reputation%20Graph) and sorted by newest. I saw the newest was two days old and figured there were no duplicates.

But there were *two* duplicates

- [Eeeek! Where did the reputation graph go?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82817/where-did-the-reputation-graph-go)
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82863/what-happened-to-reputation-graph

Why do neither of these (or my question for that matter) show up?

Comment: No use of quotes then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search term is getting remapped to the [reputation](/questions/tagged/reputation) tag and neither of those questions are tagged reputation.