# Where reputation graph can be found

Tags: support, reputation-graph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eeeek! Where did the reputation graph go?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82817/eeeek-where-did-the-reputation-graph-go)

Hi,

after some updates that passed these days I can't find reputation graph. Is there somewhere hidden or it has been canceled?

Thanks for help.

Comment: @ChrisF Hi, thanks so it's duplicate but I can't find this question because of its title - I don't use the "right" words :-)