# Where can I find the reputation graph?

Tags: support, reputation-graph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eeeek! Where did the reputation graph go?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82817/eeeek-where-did-the-reputation-graph-go)

Today, I realized reputation graph disappeared. I can't find it. Tough my reputation is not so high, looking growing reputation was the only fun of my life ;)

Where did it go?

Comment: @Brandon Agreed.