# Reputation graph not displaying details correctly?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, reputation-graph

I was trying out the reputation graph and found that the details are not displayed for the day I click. For example, If I click on today's bar, the reputation details that gets displayed is for the previous day!
[image]

In the attached graph, I click on 2011-3-18 and my rep is 45.. but instead, the details that get displayed are for the previous day which is 95 reps...

Or is this issue, only for me? I am using Google chrome 10.

Comment: Same issue, and also tried on Firefox and Safarai.

Comment: I'm getting this on Super User too.

Comment: I'm using IE8/XP, I am not seeing this, not on mine nor on yours. Here is [what I see on your graph](http://i.imgur.com/apC7w.png "It's the 45 readout correctly").

Comment: @Grace - move off the first page and check on one of the "later" pages showing earlier data.

Comment: @ChrisF [Still working fine for me. Cannot repro.](http://i.imgur.com/DtaOL.png) Tested it on Abdel as well as [your Super User account](http://i.imgur.com/mZxgo.png) and [its last page](http://i.imgur.com/03LQ3.png).

Comment: @Grace - interesting. Though I do have to go back to the last page to get it to go wrong... Something's going on.

Comment: @ChrisF and Abdel, as determined [from this bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84526/bug-in-new-reputation-bar-on-utc-1-timezones), it seems that this has to do with sitting past the UTC line. That'd explain why I can't repro it.

Comment: @Grace - it would explain why it's older posts - i.e those when I was on BST rather than GMT.

Comment: Here we are in 2016, and this bug still exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully, this is fixed with the latest deploy, which adds a secondary graph showing all daily rep changes.

This secondary graph allows a draggable selection for updating the main graph, so you can quickly view any of your historic rep changes.

There are still a few display bugs around edge cases that we'll be polishing out, so give us a day or so :)

Comment: with chrome the lower bar can't be dragged anywere. i think it's a bug. Could someone check for it?

Comment: This is **not** fixed. (or it came back)

Comment: @underscore_d can you please provide more details as to what's broken? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @JarrodDixon, thanks for your reply and interest. It is the same as above, in that clicking on one bar in the chart wrongly shows the previous days events in the list below. Let me find the other threads I read about this, including one that had a detailed explanation of where the problem arises on the JavaScript, and get back to you soon,

Comment: @JarrodDixon Here are just a few: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280904 `asked Jul 6 at 0:11` / **http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259692** `Still present as of today, on SO and SU. I'm in Germany (GMT +1), local time is 11:35. – Fabio Turati Dec 3 '15 at 10:35` / http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261160 `Seems like this is fixed in some countries, but still remains in others – Unix Jul 23 '15 at 16:37` / http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261998 `@Xufox I'm certain this will be corrected within 6-8 weeks. – SeinopSys Aug 21 '15 at 6:56` Sadly not, at least for all!

Comment: @JarrodDixon And from the 2nd, bolded link up there, here is someone's analysis of the JS, as of this Jan 9: **http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272660/307776** Btw, if you want a recording of this happening for me, just ask, though I'm sure it's easy enough to replicate by using an account with unfavoured regional settings.