# Bug in new Reputation bar on UTC 1+ timezones?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-graph, timezone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation graph not displaying details correctly?!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84373/reputation-graph-not-displaying-details-correctly)

Looks like new reputation bar's click event is one column slip off.

Please take a look following screen shots

- clicking 3/18 bar loads 3/17 data
  [image]
- clicking 3/17 bar loads 3/16 data
  [image]

**Edit**:

When I set my timezone to UTC, it looks ok, so may be, please take a look on javascript codes? :-)

[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this - it works fine for me.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, Now I know its only happen on UTC 1+ zones

Comment: Can reproduce here. In fact, I came here to report this but wasn't aware that it was linked to the time zone.

Comment: Ah, this is [what's going on here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84373/reputation-graph-not-displaying-details-correctly). Thanks for finding more info towards (keep the rep), but unfortunately I must still vote as a duplicate. I will relay this revelation, though.

Comment: holy crap, that looks identical, except mine is skeeted :P closing...