# One-off bug in reputation graph (bar chart)

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, reputation-graph

I found a possible bug in the reputation graph, i.e. the bar chart, showing reputation for each single day (go to user profile -> activity -> reputation -> graph). Actually, there seem to be two bugs, but those are probably closely related:

- all of the bars are one-off: the "half bar" for the current day shown the correct reputation, but the tool-tip shows the date of the previous day, and accordingly for all other days
- when I click the bar, the reputation breakdown below the chart shows the reputation for the previous day (i.e. the same day as in the tool-tip)

In other words, for each single day,

- the height of the bar is correct
- the reputation shown in the tool-tip is correct
- the date in the tool tip is the date of the previous day
- the reputation shown below the graph is that of the previous day

I searched for related questions, and the bug seems to be the same as [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84526/bug-in-new-reputation-bar-on-utc-1-timezones) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84373/reputation-graph-not-displaying-details-correctly), but those are 5 years old and reportedly fixed. Also, I can't remember experiencing this bug some time ago, so if this is the same bug, it must have reappeared.

Using Firefox 44.0.2 on Xubuntu 14.04, in case it matters.

Comment: Yeah, this keeps coming up. Currently, we have [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259692/reputation-for-graph-is-off-by-a-day) to point to as a dupe (as well as several closed as dupe of that), but there are several newer ones on Meta Stack Overflow as well. (And I would hazard a guess other per-site metas also have a handful of these)

Comment: @Kendra I only found the five-year-old ones, but that seems to be the same issue, too. How comes this has not yet been fixed in all that time?

Comment: That's the question of the day, far as I'm concerned. It might be it's a very, very low-priority bug for the devs.