# Reputation histogram shows rep changes for the Nth-1 day

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

When I click on the histogram's bars, it shows me the changes for the day before that. In case of rep changes after a day of nothing, it says "There were no net reputation changes on this day" when there actually were. And when you click the next day's bar, it shows you what you want to see.

See this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I can confirm this. I see the same behavior in all of my user profiles across the SE network. On SE sites where I earned rep on multiple days in a row (e.g. stackoverflow, sustainability, martialarts), the total rep listed below the graph always adds up to the total rep displayed in the graph the day before the one that was selected. So it is indeed an N-1 problem.

Comment: Seems the bug is already reported here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259692/164138 and also on stackoverflow meta http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296775/741249