# Reputation detail display on specific day

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, profile-page

After I click the [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6171361/sel-fish?tab=reputation) tab on my activity page, I can see graph like below:

[image]

Here I find out that I got 50 rep on 'May 8', then I click the banner to see detail, it turns out that the detail is about the reputation I got on 'May 7', because in the graph, there is 50 rep gained.

Comment: No need in such updates.