# Reputation graph shows events for previous day

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-graph

When I click a day column on reputation chart, events for a previous day are shown instead of events for the selected day. The column tooltip shows also previous day (the same for which events are shown), but shows total reputation for the selected day.

[image]

On the screenshot, you can see that I've clicked Jul 20, the tooltip shows July 19 and event list shows events for July 19 (30 total reputation, contrary to 90 total reputation for selected day - July 20).

Seen both on Stack Overflow and Super User.

Firefox 39.0 on Windows 8.1, if it matters.

I've seen this was reported 4 years ago already, but was fixed, so it looks like a regression.
[Reputation graph not displaying details correctly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84373/218578)

Comment: Repro on Codereview with Chrome on Linux. seems to be unrelated to browser.. off-by one ftw

Comment: Seems like this is fixed in some countries, but still remains in others