# Clicking a column in the reputation graph shows details for the previous day

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-graph

When clicking a column in the reputation graph on my profile, the previous days' details are displayed, even if no changes happened on that day. The tooltip also shows the wrong date. In the example below (taken on StackOverflow), clicking on "Aug 14" shows data for Aug 13 while the tooltip at Aug 13 shows August 12.

[image: reputation graph showing details for the wrong day]

Note that even if my question is a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84373/184030), it was closed and fixed, but the issue seems to have reappeared and as such I'm posting it again.

Browser I'm using is Opera 30.0.1835.125 on Windows 10

Comment: Repro'ed. Chrome version  44.0.2403.125 m. (Can't +1 though, votes already spent)

Comment: The same here, currently on UTC +2, with fresh Firefox.

Comment: Same here with Firefox 39, still applies, still not fixed.

Comment: @Xufox I'm certain this will be corrected within 6-8 weeks.