# Different colors for different rep types in the new reputation graph

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, reputation, daily-reputation-limit, reputation-graph

The [new reputation graph](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82817/eeeek-where-did-the-reputation-graph-go/84410#84410) is nice and the gray line at 200rep is also useful.
However it would be great when the different forms of reputation (votes, accepted answers, bounties, ...) would be colored differently.
Especially the two groups of capped rep (votes, +2 for wiki edits, ...) and uncapped rep (accepted answers, bounties, ...) should be separated.

Here the idea: The capped rep should be colored differently and be always on bottom on the bar graph. This way someone can see how far it is away from the daily rep limit. The uncapped rep is on top and can peak over the 200rep limit. There should also be an indicator whether the rep cap was hit and therefore counts for the [Epic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/51/epic) and [Legendary](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/52/legendary) badge. For example the gray line at 200rep could be thicker for that day.

Also: The reputation *lost* because of the reputation limit could be displayed as gray bar on the very top of all other rep. Seeing this would be also a nice piece of information.

The reputation which disappeared because it has been used as a bounty should also be displayed accordantly and not simply subtracted. For example if someone received 180 rep on one day and sets out a bounty of 200 rep the graph should display *two* bars one positive to 180 to indicate the achieved rep of the day and one negative to -20 to indicate the final rep. The positive bar should be in a (slightly?) different color than normal to indicate its "received but given away" status. A simple example would be a yellow positive bar and an orange (instead red) negative one. If the total rep was positive (e.g. 225 rep - 200 rep bounty) there could be a normal positive bar with 25 points and then on top the yellow one from 25-225. 
Otherwise bounties would look more like penalties.

Comment: I like this idea. It can provide some very interesting statistics, such as how often a user caps on days that they get past 200, or the average ratio of their reputation sources in general.

Comment: Also, it would be nice to see rep lost through bounties, somehow

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a great idea, but we can't implement it until some refactorings are done with how rep is denormalized from raw votes on posts.

We'll revisit it once some database changes have been made.

Comment: When you implement it, make sure the colors work for [the red-green-deficient](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92499/162565) ;) (I think Daniel's suggestion with orange, green and blue should work. Then again, the colors will probably differ from site to site.)

Comment: Is this still [meta-tag:status-deferred]?

Answer (score 7):

Good suggestion.

It'd be *especially* useful for rep cap seekers because you could see the bar for upvotes go all the way to the 200 rep line and then have accepts/bounties/etc. extend above that.

With SO as the primary example, I suggest the following color scheme:

- **upvotes**  =  the color of the highlighted/enabled vote arrow (SO: orange)
- **accepts given/received** = the color that the accept icon (SO: green)
- **bounties** = the color of the bounty amount box (SO: blue)

Having per-site color schemes *could* be confusing to users of multiple sites, though, since for example on Gaming the upvotes are blueish and the bounties are reddish (though the accepts are still green).

Comment: Red is already used when you go into negative, actually. I think that when you're still positive, that upvotes and downvotes should just be grouped together in the same color, basically constituting a "net votes" system.

Comment: Keep in mind that the color scheme of other stackexchange sites can be quite different to that on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

I love the idea of seeing the rep "lost" due to the cap in the graph. I'm not overly fussed about the rest of the suggestion, but that bit alone is easily worth a +1.

If that gets implemented, I'd also like to see it in figures on the textual report as well.

(I think I'm at 1360 lost rep for today, at the moment... it's been a fun day :)

Comment: We already hired Nick away from answering too many questions and going past you, rep-wise -- I'd say that's enough "Skeet support" for a while :)

Comment: I was just thinking about if there was some way to calculate what your rep would be if the limit weren't in place.

Comment: @Gabe: The simplest approximation is to look at the "total votes" from the reputation audit. Current value: 78040. So *on the order* of 780,000. (Some votes will be downvotes, some acceptances etc.)

Comment: Yes, but I would suspect that you have a significant amount from bounties as well. You'd have to search for all the `9` rows and add those in.

Comment: @Gabe: I don't get many bounties, actually... bounties are usually put on questions that have spent a long time unanswered... whereas if I *can* answer a question (and it doesn't already have a good answer) I've normally answered it within 24 hours.

Comment: There should be a badge for lost rep. Like when you loose more rep on one day than you actually get. Happened two me once or twice (on tex.sx). Ok, you might get annoyed getting one of these every day. :-)