# Checkmarks on new SE sites are inconvenient for red-green colorblind users

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, accepted-answer, design, accessibility

When I ask a question on some of the new SE sites (and every answer has a check mark next to it for me to select one as my accepted answer), it's very hard for me to tell the difference between the check mark that I've checked, and one that I haven't checked. I'm red-green blind, and for me the green tone of the accepted answer is very hard to tell apart from grey checkmark that has not been checked.

I had this problem on Programmers SE, [made a request](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/970/accepted-answer-checkmark-color), and they fixed it. I also had this problem on Tex SE, [and made a request that's still not answered](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/844/accepted-answer-checkmark-color).

Could you add as a general guideline when designing new sites a requirement that the checkmark change shape in a noticable way when I click to accept an answer? (For example, getting noticably bolder, or having the unchecked check-mark be an outline like on Stack Overflow.)

Also, could you prod the appropriate person at Tex SE to fix this over there?

Comment: Oh...you mean they're *not* all outlines like they are here and on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Cody: No, they're not.

Comment: Wow, shows how little I participate on the other SE sites. There's absolutely no reason for them not to be. Accessibility is an important goal around here.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with {accepted-answer}? There aren't even any answers here.

Comment: @doncherry: This question is **about** accepted answers.

Comment: Could some mod, admin, or designer at least show that they've acknowledged this question? I find it hard to believe that there hasn't been any official statement on this question whatsoever.

Comment: @doncherry: Jin just posted that the problem is solved on TeX.SX (with the next deployment): http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/844/accepted-answer-checkmark-color/1769#1769

Comment: @doncherry: [This is not a pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: There's nothing like a late-night brain-teaser, nice one :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless anybody knows of any more SE sites that need check mark fixing for red-green-blind accessibility, I think this question can be considered answered and tagged with [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) due to [Jin's answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1769/4012) on Tex SE:

> Sorry I missed this request. I have adjusted the contrast between the checkmark's on and off state significantly. This change will be in the next production build.

I would assume any future check marks will be designed accordingly.