# Color blindness. Accessibility. Impact on ability to moderate questions

Tags: feature-request, design, accessibility

[Possible duplicate question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92499/checkmarks-on-new-se-sites-are-inconvenient-for-red-green-colorblind-users)

I just realized that SO possibly blocks out many potential  Moderators from editing questions. Due to color blindness. 7 % of males are red-green color blind (source wikipedia).

**I am not saying that I know what to do about it** but it seems to me that this might be ***a fact worth pointing out***. (Perhaps some optional way of changing css template for color blind people. Yes, really).

In my biology studies I learned that *microarray literature*** (articles) f.e. *Nature journal* **has changed their color scheme for microarrays from `red-green` to `blue-yellow`** (sometimes blue-red). (No, I did not find a source to back this up, you have to take me on my word).

<sub>** Microarry. A common device to analyze gene expression (DNA, RNA).</sub>

**Microarray from** [Nature journal.](http://www.nature.com/ng/journal/v43/n12/full/ng.1004.html)

[image: A microarray from Nature journal]

**Edit of** [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8924008/revisions) **by me.**

Probably hard to see for a color blind, huh? (Perhaps an extreme example but not too uncommon).

[image: My edit]

Comment: The diffs use quite contrasting colours (along with the strikethrough indicator). It's the link and tag colour schemes on many of the sites that 'disable' me - inasmuch that links are often visually indistinguishable without manually scanning the text for underlines on hover.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I just realized that SO possibly blocks out many potential Moderators from editing questions.

How does this block editing? You don't have to be able to see diffs in order to edit.

You can also view the changed parts of a post side by side instead of combined:

[image]

which may help, depending on the kind of color blindness.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was not aware of 'side by side' feature. An option of f.e. change green to blue would be. +Better for color blind. -Introduce unnecessary complexity to the site. Leaning towards unnecessary complexity part (but I'm not color blind).

Comment: +1. Also, *are* any mods actually colorblind? Has anyone actually complained?

Comment: Since. I would like the matter to be discussed a bit more. I will wait some time before accepting your answer. (Lets say 24 h).

Comment: +1. @Unhandled Exception. YES they certainly are. If 7 - 10 % of 'male white people' are colorblind (absolutely no pun intended). Counting low (lets say 90 % mods are male, 70 % of mods comes from demographics with only 4 % color blindness) that still gives us more than 5 % mods are color blind.

Comment: @TheUnhandledException I'm sure people get sick of me complaining, especially with me not having taken the time to properly bring it up.

Comment: Okay, that settles that, thanks @Mr.Disappointment!

Comment: @TheUnhandledException Granted, that's not in regard to revision diffs; see my comment on the question.