# Should the reputation graph differentiate between points that count toward daily reputation cap and points that don't?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, daily-reputation-limit, reputation-graph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Different colors for different rep types in the new reputation graph](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84438/different-colors-for-different-rep-types-in-the-new-reputation-graph)

A user's reputation graph should differentiate between points that count toward the daily reputation cap and points that don't. That would provide a great visual aid to know how close you are to the reputation cap.

Am I misunderstanding this portion from the FAQ?

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day. Please note that
>   votes for posts marked “community wiki” do not generate any
>   reputation, while accepted answers and bounty awards are not subject
>   to the daily reputation limit.

Maybe I'm assuming in error that because accepted answers and bounty awards are not subject to the daily limit, they don't count toward badges like Mortarboard, Epic, and Legendary? Clarification either way would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seriously, why the down-vote? Is this such a bad post?

Comment: The downvoter probably just thinks your suggestion wouldn't be a good idea.

Comment: I would love to know *why* the down-voter thinks that.

Comment: I would love to know *why* people who post feature requests are so sensitive about people's varied opinions on that feature request. Why do you care so much why they disagree with your suggestion? Why do you act like it's a personal insult when they cast a vote of disagreement? Seriously, it's annoying. If they wanted to post an answer or comment that outlined their disagreement, they would have done so.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would be great! The bars in the graph would be 2 coloured, with the cap-sensitive rep being always in the low part of the bars, while the cap-insensitive rep would be in the upper part. This way one could easily see visually, if he is going to reach the cap or not!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [your reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783175/fishbasketgordo?tab=reputation) (not the graph), you can already differentiate between points that are considered for reaching the reputation cap: The numbers with a different background are not considered.