# Stacked bars for reputation diagram?

Tags: feature-request, reputation-graph

Today I read about the reputation limit on Stack Exchange; set to 200 for all others then bounties and accepted answers.

It would be nice to visualize this in reputation graphs on profile page. Maybe red colored for limited score and green for all other.

Comment: That would be nice, but if it is useful. Not sure how many users actually hit that limit regular enough to spend dev time on it. Maybe in 6 to 8 years.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84438/different-colors-for-different-rep-types-in-the-new-reputation-graph

Comment: That's already six years, so only two more to go ;)