# Global reputation graph and flair do not include sites on which I have recently reached 200 reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, reputation-graph, network-profile

I thought the global reputation graph should include those sites on which I have [at least 200 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83879/1114) but I haven't found an authoritative source for that, and that's not what I'm experiencing now.

At of the end of July 22nd my reputation on Apple.SO and Programmers.SO was over 200, higher than my score on Super User. It's been over a week and the graph still doesn't include them, even though the scores listed for the sites it does include have been kept up-to-date.

I thought this was a misunderstanding or bug just with the reputation graph. I just realized that the other sites are also missing from my global flair image, so I guess the bug is a bit more general than that.

---

[image: global flair screenshot, showing only SO, mSO and SU]
[image]
[image: a screenshot of my reputation scores, showing Apple and Programmers above SU]

---

Has anyone else passed 200 reputation and had the site show up for them within the last week? If so, the issue might be specific to my account, and I might poke someone to have them take a look at it.

Comment: On my graph, the cutoff is between 195 (not shown) and 206 (shown). The last time a site crossed the 200 mark was Jul 10, and that site is shown.

Comment: @Jeremy Have you tried running the rep recalc at `site.com/reputation`? Perhaps you have some deleted answers/questions and lost rep from that is not being calculated...

Comment: @yoda I just ran a recalc on all of the accounts mentioned in the post. None changed significantly.

Comment: hmm... then perhaps it's a glitch specific to your graph. Hopefully a dev will comeby and fix it

Comment: I'm disassociating and resassociating these accounts now.

Comment: It had no effect.

Comment: I started looking into this last week, but need someone else on the team to look into it too.  I'll make sure to raise this tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to try and get it figured out before the weekend, it slipped my mind after I got as far as I could. ):

Comment: I've found the same problem 3 years later. I opened a new report for that, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240414/reputation-200-reached-account-wasnt-yet-registered-in-combined-reputation-gra .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your [reputation graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/7dee0fe4-9eac-40f4-8521-89ce6916bd66?tab=reputation) is fixed now, and your [network flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/7dee0fe49eac40f4852189ce6916bd66.png) will look fixed as well in a day or so (it's cached for 24 hours).

The bug that affected your Programmers and Apple accounts also affected ~50 other accounts that crossed the 200-rep threshold on July 22. On that day, a glitch in one of our scheduled tasks caused duplicate user records to be inserted into the stackexchange.com database. The incomplete reputation graphs and network flair were a result of our code failing to handle the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Stupid question, but... did you by accident or otherwise click on the chart legend and disable some of your graphs?

As you can see in the screenshot below for my reputation chart, I have Stack Overflow line disabled, so only the top 4 sites now show up in the chart:

[image]

Comment: Nope, they aren't available to unselect.