# Reputation 200 reached, account wasn't yet registered in combined reputation graph yet

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation-graph

It seems a different, although related problem as my [another long-standing one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231976/inconsistent-buggy-combined-flair-behavior-when-reputation-is-exactly-200), although maybe it were more efficient if they were fixed in the same sprint. Please don't sign this question as duplicate, they aren't.

There is also a [very similar bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99615/global-reputation-graph-and-flair-do-not-include-sites-on-which-i-have-recently) from 2011. I also don't think they were related, during this 3 years probably not too many part of the SE engine left unchanged.

So, my problem is that although I've recently stepped over the reputation 200 on [electronics SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/35118/peter-horvath), but my [combined reputation graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/1988549/peter-horvath?tab=reputation) of meta doesn't show my reputation there.

Maybe it is related to the significant number of my 200+ SE accounts, but I must also mention, there is at least one [SE user](https://stackexchange.com/users/2728/graviton?tab=reputation) having more as twice as me.

I suspect here a bug.

*P.s. I suggest a better fix as last time (somebody quickly upvoted me somewhere...)*

*P.s.2.* Finally it appeared, but it took around 2 days.

Comment: Surely not related to the amount of 200+ accounts, see [Jeff's graph](http://stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=reputation).

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank you. Can you imagine, what could be the cause of the problem? Do you thinks also it is maybe a bug?

Comment: Wild guess is that you don't have any recent "reputation events" like posting question or answer, getting upvote, etc. So whatever job responsible for syncing the network wide reputation used in the graph didn't run.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, of course there is none, I must be inactive on the site to hold the bug-reproducible state until it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to blame some sort of caching here because I see Electrical Engineering in your rep list when I check it now:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is working since around 12 hours. But it took 2 days to appear.