# time - upvote plots

Tags: feature-request

In the user info, it would be nice to have plots marking for each question a little question mark and for each answer a little exclamation mark in the time-upvote plane, so that one can see at a single glance when someone has posted good questions or answers.

Note that this is different from the old reputation graph
[Eeeek! Where did the reputation graph go?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82817/)
which reported total reputation.

I suggest to provide a graph that shows for each question and answer a single mark ? or !, at the point in time (x-axis) where the question was asked or the answer was supplied, and with the net number of upvotes as height (y-axis). 
I'd like see all questions and answers in a single plot, with just one ? or ! mark in the time x votecount plane to summarize its value.
This gives quite different and much more useful information.

If these marks are clickable and lead to the corresponding title and a link, this would be really useful!

Comment: My request is quite different from what the old reputation graph provided. See the edited question.

Comment: You  could get this mugrated to MSO if you wanted a quick answer...

Comment: @dmckee: This is far too detailed. i want to see all questions and answers in a single plot, with just one ? or ! mark in the time x votecount plane to summarize its value. - Yes, migrating would be fine, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier Just flag the post for mod attention and write "migrate please". Anyways, it's migrated now.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier http://stackapps.com/questions/2202/reputation-graph

Comment: @Manishearth: This plot conveys only a cumulative reputation number, which is far off from what i suggested above.

Comment: I know, but it could be of some use. If that was the solution then I'd have posted it as an answer :)