# Network profile reputation graph

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-graph, network-profile

I have 11 accounts under my network profile, but I've noticed only the top 2 (in terms of rep) show on the Reputation graph.

Show all accounts display or is there a particular reason only showing some accounts?

Comment: Only accounts for which you have a minimum of 200 rep will show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Reputation graph shows accounts on which you have more than 200 reps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83879/166025).

Comment: Any reason it only shows sites with over 200 rep?

Comment: @SteB I am not sure but this restriction could be in place to avoid load on servers as there could be many occasional users having less than 200 reps.