# Why does the "Code of Conduct" mention a very controversial company (Google) by name?

Tags: discussion, code-of-conduct

In the official [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), which has been copied to every other community, Google is mentioned by name.

People with an IT affinity often [use alternative search engines](https://www.privacyguides.org/search-engines/) because they not agree with the surveillance capitalism, censorship and advertising, of Google.

Can this sentence be formulated independently of the manufacturer?

[image]

Comment: It's written that way because people write that exact line all the time in comments.

Comment: "To google" is a verb meaning "to use a search engine to look things up on the web", so the word itself is fine. It probably shouldn't be capitalized though.

Comment: @cigien: [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/google) has: *to use the **Google** search engine to obtain information about (someone or something) on the World Wide Web*.

Comment: @Justin Hmm, interesting. I've been using the term "to google" for years, but have been using DDG as the search engine primarily for some time now. Maybe the term is not actually used in the generic sense. FreeDictionary says "To search for information online via a search engine, typically Google." https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/To+google

Comment: Well, keep in mind you are mentioning a company "controversial" in another company also "controversial". No one has completely clean hands in this globalization.

Comment: @cigien: Yeah, the definitions vary across dictionaries; some imply that it can be applied to other search engines as well, while some dictionaries specifically refer to the term as the use of the *Google* search engine to find information ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/google), [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/google), etc.).

Comment: @Justin I'm googling (:p) this, and it looks like Google objected to it being used generically, http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/3006486.stm and there's court cases and stuff https://law.justia.com/cases/federal/appellate-courts/ca9/15-15809/15-15809-2017-05-16.html All good then, I'll continue using it like I have been. Google can sue me if they don't like it, they have my contact info I'm sure ;)

Comment: – *Why does the "Code of Conduct" mention a very controversial company (Google) by name?* – Because SE is not an ONG or a governmental site, not even a democracy, is a [private company](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76352/391011).

Comment: Because of the strong feelings that occasionally arise when mentioning a specific search engine, I generally "ask the bingleduck" instead of "[Gg]oogling".

Comment: They misspelled the ***verb*** *"[google](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/google#Verb_2)"*. Even if it is an example, why would they misspell it? It just distracts from the message.

Answer (score 14):

It's gotten genericized  - I've never heard anyone talk about "binging" a search result (and I don't know what's the equivalent for DuckDuckGo).

It's there because people *literally* say this. We even were asked to block [lmgfy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15650/135565) because it was an issue (I'm half certain it's in a naughty list, but I'm not sure).

If nothing else, it's an example of being condescending, and would be the same with any other search engine.

Comment: Google with a capital G is a noun. The verb form shouldn't be capitalized, i.e. "You could try googling it, but half the people on the Internet are wrong." If "Google" wasn't capitalized, there's a good chance no-one would have complained because its generic nature would have been obvious. Yes, capitalization and punctuation DO matter :)

Comment: The equivalent would of course be DuckDuckGo**ing**

Comment: @Ramhound Folks would probably shorten that to "Ducking" :)

Comment: There is a joke around that word…

Comment: Well, [binging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRy6C.png) is already taken for other meanings. :D

Comment: "binging" a search result is often used when making fun of Microsoft's offering, for example, on the *[.NET Rocks](https://www.dotnetrocks.com/)* podcast.